# Is there a philosophical or mathematical proof for "For any observation or claim, there's an infinite number of assumptions we presume to be true?"

Tags: logic, epistemology, metaphysics, infinity

Is there a philosophical or mathematical proof for "For any observation or claim, there's an infinite number of assumptions we presume to be true?"

It doesn't seem to make any sense, but what I am trying to claim is that you can write any statement or set of statements that is presumed and has to be presumed to be true for any observation or claim to be true, and then decompose that statement or set of statements into an infinite number of statements. I am thinking there might be a simple example that might disprove this claim, and that's why I am asking this question.

Comment: So you claim that it's not the case, but is there a subset of claims or propositions where this might be true then?

Comment: If by 'things' most likely meant by you to be propositions then the universal claim to 'know all provable propositions within PA exhaustively' needs an infinite number of propositional axioms including PA's induction axiom scheme. Of course if it's just some modest particular claim such as '1+2=3' or  'for all n, n^2=(n+1)(n-1)', you only need very few finite axioms with your language...

Comment: What exactly do you mean with that sentence? ""For any observation or claim..." example: "Today (Feb.8, 2024) at half past eight AM the sun is raising"? "...an infinite number of things we presume to be true" What kind of "things" we presume?

Comment: You can split any "presumption" into "infinite number of things", so this sort of "counting" is completely meaningless. And for any statement we "presume" at least the concepts that make it sensible, so there is trivially always some "presumption" available. This question does not just seem to make no sense, it does make no sense.

Answer (score 2):

There is a formal sense in which the mere existence of any proposition P entails the truth of an infinite number of other propositions; P doesn't even have to be true. If P is true, let P1 be the true proposition "P is true". If P is false, let P1 be the true proposition "P is false". Then let P2 be the true proposition "P1 is true", let P3 be the true proposition "P2 is true", etc. You get an infinite chain of true propositions.

If you are a deflationist, you might defeat this argument by claiming that P1 and "P1 is true" are the same proposition, so the whole chain collapses into P (if P is true) or P1 (if P is false). However, I can build up the same sort of chain using "it would be (in)correct to say that P" or something similar.

Alternatively, I could use set theory. If P exists, the set containing only P exists, and so does the set containing only the set containing P, etc. so there is an infinite chain of true propositions "{P} exists", "{{P}} exists", "{{{P}}} exists", etc.

You might want to reject all of these for being mere formalisms. I think you would have a hard time justifying that, but even if you do, then I can still make an infinite set of claims about any empirical proposition P by the following method: any empirical proposition that is ever true is true for some duration of time. Let's say P is true from t1 to t2, so the proposition "P from t1 to t2" is true. Let t3 be a time halfway between t1 and t2, so the proposition "P from t1 to t3" is true. Let t4 be a time halfway between t1 and t3, so the proposition "P from t1 to t4" is true, etc. Another infinite chain.

Answer (score 2):

One tack you might take is to concede that propositions are constructs of natural language. **Since natural language is largely considered a result of [generative grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_grammar), there is no theoretical constraint on the linguistic constructs which embody propositions.** Consider the following.

> There is foo.

In this sentence, foo is a complement to the copula 'is' that is inhabited either by a predicate adjective or predicate noun. Is there a theoretical limit to what can inhabit the position of the verbal complement in this case? No, and that's because nouns and adjectives are [open classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech#Open_and_closed_classes). **Thus, it's hard to conceive of how cannot create a proposition in a practically endless fashion.**

Another example of the generative power of grammar is using a number system to generate a complement.

> There is n thing(s).

Notice, **there are an infinite number of propositions available because there are an infinite number of n's if n is taken to be a natural number which are adjudged infinite**. The same could be said about using natural numbers to indicate times t:

> There is a house at time t.

So mechanically, there is no constraint on generating meaningful propositions. This is called [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion). In fact, **this fact has been recognized since ancient times, and in philosophy carries with it the name [infinite regress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_regress)**. From WP:

> In the epistemic regress, for example, a belief is justified because it is based on another belief that is justified. But this other belief is itself in need of one more justified belief for itself to be justified and so on. An infinite regress argument is an argument against a theory based on the fact that this theory leads to an infinite regress.

**Is there a proof? Well, that depends on your notion of evidence and proof which is a function of your mathematical and epistemic presumptions**. For instance, some mathematicians reject [actual infinity](https://_), which complicates the discussion about infinite regress. That being said, it's a rather well accepted principle that infinite regress is a problem. In fact, it was one of the [Agrippan tropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrippa_the_Skeptic#The_five_modes_of_Agrippa) and is still regularly invoked, even on this forum.